# From what object do you get a revised files properties from SharpSVN [c#]?

Tags: c#, properties, sharpsvn

I've been working with SharpSVN for a few weeks now and I was looking to access an individual files properties (at a specific revision) as you can in TurtoiseSVN by clicking on the revision then right clicking on a path and selecting 'Show Properties'. I have looked where I would assume these properties would be located (under a SvnChangeItem) because it would make sense there since in Turtoise its basically a drill down however I have not been able to find it. Currently I have access to the changed items at a specific revision but just cannot find this collection. I also checked other various places where this collection might be found but with no luck. Thanks.

Comment: I believe I may have stumbled on the correct path looking again once more through the documentation.

Comment: No dice >.< still unable to find how.

Answer (score 2):

You can access these via SvnClient.GetProperty or .ListProperties. To get them for a specific revision you should create an SvnUriTarget(, revision) and pass that as the first argument.